# How can i use DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey in another column?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, uuid

I have DynamoDB table and i am using `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` for generating a key. I have a other column named `directory` and i want to use that auto generated ID value in that column.

For example If

`id=3ea8e671-1e64-4cde-bd78-5980049a772b`

then i want to insert

`directory=/3ea8e671-1e64-4cde-bd78-5980049a772b`

I don't want to use the `UUID.randomUUID()`. One other option is updating the column after getting the id generated. In that case i need to insert first and then update that column. How can i do that in a single db operation?

Comment: Is the requirement to duplicate the generated id into another column(doesn't matter if you prefix or suffix some constant)? just curious why? And if prefix/suffix can be different then why not just store them as you'll always get the generated id as part of response since its a key. So you can manipulate rather than duplicating

Answer (score 1):

`@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` is indeed `UUID.randomUUID()`.

In short to achieve what you want create another method to getId and annotate it with `@DynamoDBGeneratedUuid(DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)` and use its value in get methods for both key and column